Why does Java disallow automatic type conversion in printf?
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("%,.2f", 10000 / 3);
    }
}

This code will cause a runtime error as follows:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: f != java.lang.Integer
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Formatter.java:4515)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printFloat(Formatter.java:3079)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Formatter.java:3027)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2791)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.implFormat(PrintStream.java:1367)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.format(PrintStream.java:1346)
    at java.base/java.io.PrintStream.printf(PrintStream.java:1245)
    at Main.main(Main.java:3)

Are there specific reasons why Java disallows automatic type conversion in printf?
I searched the web, but most results only mention that the f formatter works for float, double, and BigDecimal, with few explaining the reason behind it.

"with few explaining the reason behind it". So you got your explanation. What you want now?

the signature of printf is printf(String, Object...) so the only types expected for the second parameter are Object or Object[] -- the only possible "automatic type conversion" was from int to Integer, which fits an Object (also called as auto-boxing) -- the compiler has no knowledge of how the method will interpret %,.2f, and printf is not specified to type convert an Integer to a floating point

I suspect the real answer is "because Java 1.0 was designed to be very C-like, and %f on an int is undefined behavior (UB) in C, but Java has always tried to avoid UB; so they picked the closest/safest translation from C's UB, which is "throw an error so that people won't do that".

javadoc: "The following conversions may be applied to float, Float, double and Double." -- and: "Also, Java formatting is more strict than C's; for example, if a conversion is incompatible with a flag, an exception will be thrown."

@yshavit interesting theory, but printf was introduced in 1.5. Way after Format, introduced in 1.1 which have no problem with converting Integers to doubles.

There is no technical reason for printf not to accept Integer in this case. If you interested in why such decision was made you need to ask your question in different place. History is off-topic here.

Well, it's probably a bug if someone thought they were printing a float but weren't, so you should probably let them know..

@talex Ah, good catch!

@talex I was just wondering if there's a specific reason behind it. After your explanation, I realize it might be purely coincidental. That's fine.

example of a possible specific reason: lets assume 10 / n is to be printed as %,.2f with n = 3, but the developer forgot that n is an int - if the Integer was (silently) accepted, the result would be 3,00  instead of 3,33 - no hint that the value is wrong

Another possible reason is: why would you ever want to format an integer using a decimal point? I've seen horrible things like "4.00 items" in invoices, which is nonsense when individual items cannot be split. It's a good thing printf doesn't allow you to do such stupid things.

First of all, if you were hoping that it would print 333.3..., I am going to disappoint you: that was never going to happen.
That is because the expression 1000 / 3 evaluates to the integer number 333, no ands, no ifs, no buts, period, end of story. It is an integer. As a matter of fact, the expression 1000 / 3 is red herring in this question; you could have asked the same question substituting 333 in place of that 1000 / 3, and the question would have been more clear.
Now, you might be wondering why it completely refused to work instead of automatically converting that integer 333 to a float 333.0f so as to at least print 333.0....
There are two places where such a conversion could conceivably happen: either at the call site, (by the compiler,) or within the printf() function.
Conversion by the compiler:
The compiler can, under many circumstances, perform an automatic conversion of an int to a float, but in order to do that, it must have a hint that a float is expected. However, in this case, the compiler knows nothing of the System.out.printf() function and its bizarre format specifiers, and therefore it knows nothing of the "%f" that you passed. All that the compiler knows is that the function accepts an array of Object, so it needs to box that int into an Integer, (which is an Object,) and that is all it does.
Conversion within the printf() function:
Programmers very often make mistakes when trying to use printf(), so the function tries to be as type-safe as possible. Being type-safe means that we refrain from making arbitrary conversions, and we require types to exactly match, or else we issue errors. That's why if you say that you intend to print a floating-point number, the printf() function expects nothing but a value of type Float, Double, or BigDecimal.

Note that Java allows some automatic conversions, such as int n = 333; double d = n;. We can also pass an int to a method that takes double. But we just can't pass an int to printf when the format requires a double (or other floating-point type).

Also, because printf is a var arg (variable argument) method, it can't actually take types like int and double.  Those are boxed and passed as Integer and Double.  That might have something to do with printf's unique behavior.

@k314159 I amended the answer to take your comment into account.

@markspace as you wrote, readers can get the impression that varargs (variable arity parameter) cannot be primitives, that varargs is the reason for auto-boxing - that is not the case - printf arguments (but the first) may be of different types and any type is accepted, so it must be Objects

Your ideas about reasons behind printf() behavior not supported by fact that other methods have no problem with converting int to double. I think this question is unanswerable unless we find actual eyewitness to testify.

You mean it expects Float, Double, or BigDecimal.

@talex: The printf call, though, isn't trying to convert int to double -- Java doesn't even know to try.  It's just boxing up what's there as an Integer, because that's what ints box to, to stuff it into the Object[].  Then printf is trying to treat the Integer as a Double, which isn't possible since the two classes are not related like that.

@cHao well MessageFormat.format have no problem in same situation. Which mean that was deliberate choice, not technical restriction.

Sorry for the confusion of using 1000 / 3.

@talex: Deliberate choice or oversight.  In any case, that kind of magic is not there unless someone explicitly codes it in, and the code's simpler if you don't.  printf didn't.
